# How to remove giant padlock symbol from nautilus's display of read-only files?

Tags: nautilus

To avoid accidental damage, my photographs are kept as read-only files (-r--r--r--).

Unfortunately, they appear like this in [nautilus](/questions/tagged/nautilus):
[image: Screenshot showing photo thumbnails obscured by large padlock symbol.]

How can I configure nautilus to not obscure the images with the worse than useless, giant padlock symbol?

#### UPDATE:

I tried replacing `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/256x256/emblems` with a link to `../8x8/emblems` hoping it would use the smaller icon.

Unfortunately it insisted on using the original huge size, and simply expanded the 8x8 image into a fuzzy padlock.

And of course even that useless fix requires root privileges.

And if the image is also a symlink it gets even worse:

[image: photograph obscured by two huge icons]

What is the purpose of `nautilus` if it isn't to browse images in a directory?

This insistence on obscuring the image is really silly.

Answer (score 2):

[chattr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) is meant to make files immutable without changing ownership or permissions on files so I would suggest changing your permissions from "read" back to "read+write" and then set the immutable bit them.

```
cd to_dir
chmod 600 {files}
sudo -i
cd to_dir
chattr +i {files}
```

... and no more padlock.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably require editing source code to remove this behavior of displaying an emblem on read only files. A hack that may remove these emblems would be to replace the corresponding icons in your icon theme by e.g. transparent png graphics. The responsible icon here is named "emblem-readonly". You would need to replace all variations (i.e. different resolutions) of this icon in the theme folder under `/usr/share/icons`. They are found under "emblems" folders under each of size variations. For example, the 32 × 32 version of the icon for the default icon theme of Ubuntu, Yaru, is found under `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/512x512/emblems/emblem-readonly.png`.

Perhaps just deleting these icons (i.e., better renaming them so you could restore) may already do the trick.

Issue: this is a coarse trick and may affect other applications that may use these emblems.